# Is this German?

Tags: word-usage

Could you please tell me if this conversation was opened in German?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ys5WwsZMvr8

Truly,

Steven Dott

Comment: @Takkat: Beides ist nicht notwendig, denn es gibt ganz einfach keinen Grund diese Frage zu schließen. Diese Frage ist on-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be relevant only a short period of time, and it lacks context to see why it should be related to the German language. In addition, general interest is doubtful and it is unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

No, it definitely is not German. I have no idea, what language it is, but it doesn't even sound like any germanic language. Maybe it is Arabic?